# SQL Server - Maintenance - How to obtain duration per database from the commandlog table

Tags: sql-server, maintenance

Attempting to obtain the duration for individual maintenance operations per database in the commandlog table which is available in [Ola Hallengren's](https://ola.hallengren.com/) maintenance scripts

[image]

If anyone has a better solution to this, I'd love to hear from you.

```
set dateformat mdy
DECLARE @months AS int = -3
/*
DBCC_CHECKDB,UPDATE_STATISTICS,ALTER_INDEX,BACKUP_DATABASE,BACKUP_LOG
*/
DECLARE @operation AS varchar(50) = 'BACKUP_DATABASE'
DECLARE @datbasename as varchar(255) = 'Logs'

SELECT @operation
DECLARE @commandsql as varchar(max)
set @commandsql = '
;WITH reindex_table as (
SELECT TOP (1000)
      [DatabaseName]
      ,[StartTime]
      ,[EndTime]
      ,DATEDIFF(MI,StartTime,EndTime) as duration
      ,convert(varchar, StartTime, 23) as operationdate
      ,ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by convert(varchar, StartTime, 23) order by convert(varchar, StartTime, 23) desc) ''rownumber''
  FROM [_DBA_Tools].[dbo].[CommandLog]
  where 1=1
  And CommandType = '''+ @operation +'''
  And DatabaseName = ''' + @datbasename + '''
  and StartTime >= DATEADD(MONTH, '+cast(@months as varchar(100))+', GETDATE())  and StartTime <=  GETDATE()
 order by id desc
 ) SELECT DatabaseName, max(convert(varchar, StartTime, 23)) as maintenance_date , sum(duration) as duration
 FROM reindex_table
 --where duration > 1
 group by operationdate, DatabaseName
 order by operationdate
 '
 PRINT @commandsql
 EXEC (@commandsql)
```

The commandlog doesn't have an id that regroups operations that were all run from the same job execution.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using dynamic SQL? If not, my first suggestion is to use a static parameterized query.

Comment: Have you considered using the SQL Agent job history for calculating the during, rather than `CommandLog`? Or does your scenario/requirements necessitate your current approach?

Comment: Hello @AMtwo, yes I did, but I am looking for the duration of each listed maintenance operation per database. The question has been updated to reflect that.

Comment: @Craig I usually schedule each discrete task as a separate job step, as it's easier to track duration and easier to resume a failed job part way through.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are interested at object level duration or at further detailed level(Index level). I use below query to get details:

```
SELECT DatabaseName,
       SchemaName,
       ObjectName,
       CASE WHEN ObjectType = 'U' THEN 'USER_TABLE' WHEN ObjectType = 'V' THEN 'VIEW' END AS ObjectType,
       IndexName,
       CASE WHEN IndexType = 1 THEN 'CLUSTERED' WHEN IndexType = 2 THEN 'NONCLUSTERED' WHEN IndexType = 3 THEN 'XML' WHEN IndexType = 4 THEN 'SPATIAL' END AS IndexType,
       PartitionNumber,
       ExtendedInfo.value('(ExtendedInfo/PageCount)[1]','int') AS [PageCount],
       ExtendedInfo.value('(ExtendedInfo/Fragmentation)[1]','float') AS Fragmentation,
       CommandType,
       Command,
       StartTime,
       EndTime,
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(ss,StartTime, EndTime)/(24*3600) > 0 THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(ss,StartTime, EndTime)/(24*3600) AS nvarchar) + '.' ELSE '' END + RIGHT(CONVERT(nvarchar,EndTime - StartTime,121),12) AS Duration,
       ErrorNumber,
       ErrorMessage
FROM dbo.CommandLog
WHERE CommandType = 'ALTER_INDEX'
ORDER BY StartTime ASC
```

You may change the condition as per your need, in the above query I wanted to check which has gone through reorg or rebuild operation.